# XID error being thrown when doing appserver calls using Progress Openedge

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

We are doing some appserver calls in ABL, which should return a dataset, however most of the time it works perfectly. But a few times the appserver returns this error.

```
ERROR : XID(Yo1owa4MTcG7-XIUvxbm8Q) OK
```

Why is this error being thrown? The dataset returned contains the data needed however this causes issues further down the line of our program.

Is this an issue in Tomcat?

Comment: Presume this is the Classic Appserver? What Progress version? Is there anything of note in the AppServer logfiles?

Comment: No, this is with an PASOE, OpenEdge version 11.7.3 and nope nothing to be found there.